# Separable extensions-Need help

Tags: field-theory

Let $K \leq M \leq E$ be field extensions, with $K \leq E$ separable.

Show that the extensions $K \leq M$ and $M \leq E$ are separable.

The extension $K\leq E$  is separable if all the elements in $E$ are separable. Correct?

Any help to continue  would be appreciated.

Comment: That is correct. It is an immediate consequence of the definition that $M\colon K$ is separable. Can you see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K,M,E$ be fields s.t. $K \subseteq M \subseteq E$. Then if $E/K$ is separable also $E/M$ is. This follows from the fact that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in E$ over $M$ divides the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over K.

The separability of extension the $M/K$ is even easier to see. (I think you can see this yourself just by looking at the definition)